# Ending up with Puppet3.8.7 while trying to install puppet5

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install puppet5 on a Virtual-box CentOS-6.9.(Master)

I have typed the following commands:

1. iptables -F
2. service iptables save
3. rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
4. yum install puppet-server
5. puppet resource package puppet-server ensure=latest

Eventually when I type: **puppet --version** 
I get **3.8.7**.

How can i get puppet version 5? 
Am I missing something?

Thanks

Oz

Comment: You never actually executed a command to install Puppet. Also: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/man/resource.html.

Comment: Thanks,  so how do I actually install puppet 5?

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/install_linux.html

Answer (score 1):

Puppet 3, 4 and 5 all use different upstream yum repositories to avoid accidental upgrades to an incompatible version.

If you want to install Puppet 5 on a EL6 machine, you will want to do the following:

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet5/puppet5-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
yum install puppet-agent -y
```

Or you can use my all in one script:

https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell

Puppet 3.8.X

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet.sh | sudo sh
```

Puppet 4

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_agent.sh | sudo sh
```

Puppet 5

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_5_agent.sh | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 0):

To install Puppet5 in CentOS-7 (VM), I followed the following steps:

1) Login to your VM and **go root**

```
sudo su -
```

2) **Copy the Puppet5 link address from [yum.puppetlabs.com](https://yum.puppetlabs.com/)** according to your system architecture

```
rpm -ihv https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet5/puppet5-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
```

3) **Install Puppet server**

```
yum -y install puppetserver
```

4) Now if your check puppet version (puppet --version), it will show you error -> **-bash: puppet: command not found**. 
This is because Puppet is defined in two different paths: 
*/opt/puppetlabs/bin* and */opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin*

To resolve this, you need to add the binary in *puppet-agent.sh*:

```
vi /etc/profile.d/puppet-agent.sh
```

5) **Edit file *puppet-agent.sh***

```
# Add /opt/puppetlabs/bin to the path for sh compatible users

if ! echo $PATH | grep -q /opt/puppetlabs/bin ; then
  export PATH=$PATH:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
  export PATH=$PATH:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin
fi
```

6) **logout and login** again as root:

```
logout
sudo su -
```

7) **Check Puppet Version**

```
puppet --version
```